# How do i stop my css animation

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I am trying to stop a animation with `:hover`, but no matter what I try it isn't working. I have tried the `animation-play-state: paused;` and other tricks, this is messing with me for about 4 days now.

Here is my code on https://jsfiddle.net/jbnx9gf8/ and a sample of what isn't working.

```
.circle:hover{
     transform: scale(2,2);
     margin:auto;
     -webkit-animation-play-state: paused; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

The animation has to stop when hovered and continue when not hovered i got it to get bigger but thats it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You applied animation on `circle:before`, so if you want to pause the animation you've to code it as :

`.circle:hover:before{animation-play-state: paused;}`

and it will work for you. Check your [Edited fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vinayofficial/jbnx9gf8/12/) here.

Comment: this is the correct answer, wanted to post the same ;]

Comment: If i am not asking to much, do you know how can i stop all of the circles if i hover one?

Comment: @jonny yes, It is possible. You can add a new class `css_pause` in CSS stylesheet and toggle it on JQuery `mouseenter` and `mouseout`. [check the fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/jbnx9gf8/13/)